# nopcommerce payment plugin

Tags: nopcommerce

I have developed a payment plugin that works with redirection logic. I used as guide the Paypal standard and MyGateVirtual
My problem is that after the user confirms the order he is redirected to the paycenter site where he inputs his credit card data and the paycenter site returns to our site in  specified urls for success and failure
In the success action of my payment controller,if the payment was not accepted for some reason, I want to redirect the user to orderdetails so he can resubmit his payment.
I use a view with the following code fragment for a button that is supposed to redirect the user to orderdetails

```
@{ var storeLocation = Nop.Core.Infrastructure.EngineContext.Current.Resolve<Nop.Core.IWebHelper>().GetStoreLocation() + Url.RouteUrl("OrderDetails", new {orderId = Model.OrderId});}


<input type="button" name="orderdetails" value="@T("Account.CustomerOrders.OrderDetails")" id="orderdetails" class="orderdetailsbutton" onclick="setLocation('@(storeLocation)'" />
```

But nothing happens if the user clicks the button.
The onclick event handler is not redirecting to orderdetails.
Please help with this issue

George

Answer (score 4, accepted):

setLocation() is a JS function defined in public.common.js. I would take the following step to diagnose the problem:

1. Check if public.common.js is properly included in your page.
2. Check if the 'storeLocation' variable is generating the correct URL. You actually don't need the front part, just the part starting with 'Url.RouteUrl' will do, since you are already in your own site.
3. Set a breakpoint in the Developer Tool of your browser, and check if setLocation is properly called, and what's the error if it's not.

With a closer look at your code, it turns out that the JS code is not well-formed (less one parenthesis).

This is  your code:

```
setLocation('@(storeLocation)'
```